# Order in order without using events

Tags: php, mysql

My MYSQL table has following structure:

```
+------+----------+-----+-----------+----------------+----------+
| uuid | username | ... | clan_rank | user_is_online | last_act |
+------+----------+-----+-----------+----------------+----------+
```

When user is on a website, i perform ajax request that updates `last_act` field and sets `user_is_online` to true in the table every 30 seconds. Using local machine i can enable event that will change `user_is_online` to false whenever `NOW() - last_act > 30`. This is used to print all friends accoring to their status. However i also need to order users by their `clan_rank` inside sorted order by `user_is_online`. Using events, this is easily achieved by this queries:

`'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_is_online = 1 ORDER BY clan_rank DESC'`

`'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_is_online = 0 ORDER BY clan_rank DESC'`

Queries above will first print all online users and order them by their clan rank, and then print all offline users with same order.

But unfortunately on my hosting i am unable to set `Event scheduler status` to ON state, and this is where i get problem of printing users in desired order.

My idea that i should replace `user_is_online = 1/0` with `NOW() - c_last_act < 30` in my queries, but is it a good solution? Maybe there are more efficient ones?

Comment: If you have an index on `last_act` then it should be efficient. Use `c_last_act > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 second`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can do this in a single query by using the WHERE as an ORDER itself; it will filter to the top all the ones where they are online and continue with the ones that are offline:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ('.time().' - c_last_act < 30) DESC, clan_rank DESC
```

Comment: Why i didnt thought about ordering by `user_is_online` replacement? Thanks for great answer, it works like a charm now

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so changing my current queries to

```
'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ('.time().' - c_last_act <= 30) ORDER BY clan_rank DESC'

'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ('.time().' - c_last_act > 30) ORDER BY clan_rank DESC'
```

did what i want.

In addition, i noticed that using `NOW()` in query from PHP gave me some odd results since server time is not setted to the GMT one.

Comment: Another note: as it stands now users that were last online EXACTLY 30 seconds ago will disappear from the list. This will cause weird glitches. You should add an equals sign to one of the two queries.